# Lambda getting access denied even though it has the necessary permissions

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a lambda that is sourced to fire whenever a new csv file is added to an s3 bucket. It parses the csv file into the individual rows of the csv and puts them into an sqs queue to be processed further.

The problem is that even though the lambda has the appropriate permissions (s3:GetObject for arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*), it always fails with a access denied error when trying to execute the GetObject function.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that file name as received by the lambda was encoded wrong, causing the lambda to look for a non-existent file.

AWS treats looking for a non-existent file the same as trying to access a restricted resource which is why I was receiving the somewhat misleading Access Denied error.

To fix, I changed the file naming schema to a simpler one unaffected by the encoding. This fixed it.